# how can I put 3D object fixed in scene with arjs sourcetype: webcam

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js, webcam.js

I have reproduce a web site with A-frame ar and  as you can see : https://medium.com/@urish/web-powered-augmented-reality-a-hands-on-tutorial-9e6a882e323e

When i put one cube with a fingertap/mouseclick on the screen of my cellphone, i can see this cube in my environnement (AR), my camera move with me, and the cube remains attached to its coordinates even if my camera leaves the view of the object to return to it. I can see one element in relation to another.

I do the same with , but this time the cube does not stay at this place in the real environment, but follows my webcam. How a can do the same as my first example? 
I think this is caused to the webcam, and that I have no real depth but i not sure.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the examples of the medium article with pure Aframe and outside of the special browser?